# Is making napalm illegal in Washington state?

Tags: washington

Is making it illegal in WA? Can I make it but not use it?  Is there a special place/location where it must be used? These are all questions that have baffled me for a while now.

Comment: What are you planning on using the napalm for?

Comment: I am not planning to use it to harm other people or their property in any way

Comment: The other question is how much napalm are you planning to make. This won't effect the legality too much... But will effect what watchlist you get put on as you purchase the supplies

Comment: No more than a couple liters i think

Comment: Your user name might hinder defense counsel strategy...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is illegal. See [State v. K.E., Respondent](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/court/wa-court-of-appeals/1481277.html) (1999), who created gasoline-styrofoam napalm, and was convicted of violating [RCW 9.40.120](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9.40.120) (possession, manufacture of disposition of an incendiary device). That is defined as "any material, substance, device, or combination thereof which is capable of supplying the initial ignition and/or fuel for a fire and is designed to be used as an instrument of wilful destruction". The law is framed in terms of the what use underlies the design of the substance, not the individual's personal intent behind possessing or making the substance (defendant's actual use was to light paper in a fireplace).

Comment: There were some pretty major extenuating circumstances in the case you linked to!  “Designed to be used as an instrument of willful destruction” probably wouldn’t be detected or prosecuted if used in private fireplaces, UNLESS maybe you also committed armed robbery and broke into a vacant house…. I use gasoline to help start fires in my yard, would adding a few styrofoam pellets make it illegal?

Comment: BTW, liquid accelerants with thickening agents are sold commercially for starting pellet stoves, (I used it all the time in my last house) so design and intent are clearly linked.